# psExec processus no window

Tags: process, window, session, psexec

When I execute `psExec -d -i -s \host -u "user" -p "password" "path"`, my application is launched but in the process (service task manager) and there is no window.

Is that normal? Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

To help the people who has the same problem: add the session's ID after `-s`.